# Send multiple requests with Fetch API and wait for their completion before executing another code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I've got too many fetch api requests and some code after that. I want Fetch API to send requests asynchronously but wait for their results before executing next code.

code example:

```
fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: someData}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => { if(data.STATUS === 'SUCCESSFUL'){ //some code here } });
fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: someData}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => { if(data.STATUS === 'SUCCESSFUL'){ //some code here } });
fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: someData}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => { if(data.STATUS === 'SUCCESSFUL'){ //some code here } });

//some code to run after above requests processing.
```

Same multiple fetch requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: someData}), // first fetch
  fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: someData}), // second fetch
  ...
]).then((data) => {
  const [firstFetchResult, secondFetchResult, ...] = data;
  // data processing
}).then(() => {
  // some code to run after above requests processing.
})
```

If you have some custom logic for every fetch result - you can use some map for custom functions. In this example mapping is based on `map()` index (callback's second argument):

```
// Some functions map - first custom functions for first fetch ect;
const FM_MAP = [
  (data) => data.substring(40, 50).replace('a', 'b'),
  (data) => data.substring(1, 10),
  (data) => [...data.substring(25, 30)].join('-_-')
]

Promise.all([
  fetch('google.com'),
  fetch('google.com'),
  fetch('google.com')
]).then((responses) => Promise.all(
  // you can work with responses just like with regular arrays
  responses
    .map((response, index) => response.text().then((data) => {
      // custom functions for every data result
      console.log(FM_MAP[index](data))
    }))
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your fastest reply! How would I know that which request's result is stored in which index of the array. because I've got some code for each request's result. I've also showed in my code that I have wrote some code on every fetch response.

Comment: Response indexes are same as requests - result for first fetch would be first element in responses array, second for second etc. Also updated answer for custom results processing;